# I can't get my CardLayout to switch cards using a button

Tags: java, user-interface, cardlayout

I'm trying to have CardLayout change the content of panel (for content in a different class) using buttons, but for some reason the button (Add New Project) doesn't do anything when clicked.

The event listener for the Add New Project button is trying to reach to a different class (the NewProject class)

```
    ...
//CardLayout variables
private JPanel cardPanel;
private static final String CARD_PROJECTTAB = "Card Project Tab";
private static final String CARD_NEWPROJECT = "Card Add Project";
private NewProject newProject;
//private TabPanel tp = new TabPanel();

//

public ProTab(){

//Create cardPanel the panel that holds all the cards.
cardPanel = new JPanel();
cardPanel.setLayout(new CardLayout(0,3));       

//Creating the proPanel that holds all other panels (below cardPanel)
proPanel = new JPanel();
proPanel.setBackground(new Color(204, 255, 102));


/*
  ==========================
  CardLayout Class Instances
  ==========================
*/

cardPanel.add(proPanel, CARD_PROJECTTAB);
newProject = new NewProject();
cardPanel.add(newProject, CARD_NEWPROJECT);

//Creating the contentPane that holds all GUI components and
//uses vertical/horizontal sidebars as needed
contentPane = new JPanel();
contentPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

//Giving the contentPane the GridBagLayout
contentPane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
GridBagConstraints g = new GridBagConstraints();
g.insets = new Insets(20,0,0,0);

...

//Project bottom buttons START

 bButtonsPanel = new JPanel();
 bButtonsPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
 bButtonsPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0,0,0,0, Color.gray));
 bButtonsPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    g.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_END;
    g.gridx = 0;
    g.gridy = 2;
    contentPane.add(bButtonsPanel, g);

viewProjectButton = new JButton("View Selected Project");
addProjectButton = new JButton ("Add a New Project");

bButtonsPanel.add(viewProjectButton);
bButtonsPanel.add(addProjectButton);

addProjectButton.addActionListener(new buttonListener());

//Project bottom buttons END

}

//Project bottom buttons ActionListeners
private class buttonListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
        if (ae.getSource() == addProjectButton){
        CardLayout cl = (CardLayout) cardPanel.getLayout();
        cl.show(cardPanel, CARD_NEWPROJECT);
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. My mistake wasn't in the implementation of CardLayout but that I fail to call the JPanel containing CardLayout properly from another c

Before //getProTab() is a method that returns a JPanel with Project Tab elements.

```
    pt = new ProTab();
    tabPane.addTab("Projects", pt.getProTab());
    tabPane.setBackgroundAt(2, (new Color(204, 255, 102)));
```

After //getCardPanel() is a new method I made to return the JPanel that holds all cards (including     // the proPanel panel)

```
    pt = new ProTab();
    tabPane.addTab("Projects", pt.getCardPanel());
    tabPane.setBackgroundAt(2, (new Color(204, 255, 102)));
```